# How to handle json data with additional strings?with URL at Android?How can i do this in gson?

Tags: android, json, string, url, gson

The JSON data URL:
http://fgo6.emscloud.net/json/solarReportData.go?callback=json&reportType=W_w&reportDate=2013-4-15

I am a beginner of **Android**.
I solve this question as follows.

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    //static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static JSONArray jAry = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "utf8"), 9999999);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            //handle strings
            json = json.substring(json.indexOf("n")+2, json.length()-1);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON array
        try {
            jAry = new JSONArray(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jAry;

    }

}
```

I am confused about this question, if you can describe it the more detailed the better.

Comment: There is [documentation for gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide), there are [tutorials](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html) and you can search the internet for information.

Comment: You probably don't want "callback=json" in the URL. This wraps the JSON in a function, which is pretty much a web browser thing. Try this URL: http://fgo6.emscloud.net/json/solarReportData.go?reportType=W_w&reportDate=2013-4-15

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It really helpful.
By the way,what's the key word should be used  in learning URL function.